# No matching binary found error

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, crash, windb

I am trying to debug a crash minidump.
 have the release debug symbols and release binaries same as crash.

While debugging that crash and pointing to symbols still I am getting "No matching binary found" error .

I am using the right symbols, binaries and pointing to right location.

So why this can happen? I can see a slight difference in timestamp of dll loaded in VS(9:03AM)  and the release binary(9:04AM)

Can this be the reason for the error?

Any solutions for this , I need to fix the crash and since this crash occuring on client machine , I cannt repro it.

Comment: Just a a guess, is it a 32bit vs 64bit issue?

Comment: Yes, the timestamp should be the same of course.  Review your build process and make sure you didn't copy the DLL before some kind of post-link build step, like mt.exe

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873210/symbols-pdb-for-native-dll-are-not-loaded-due-to-post-build-step

Answer (score 2):

You may try to debug the dump using the windbg/ntsd (from the 'Debugging tools for Windows' package that comes with Windows SDK ). There you may try to load the symbols while ignoring a  mismatch in the .pdb file versions '.reload /i' command.

Answer (score 0):

For us it was because of the name of the `pdb` file. Make sure that the executable name and debug info file name match.
Right names are `MyAwesomeApp.exe` with `MyAwesomeApp.pdb`.

If your pipeline *by any chance* renames the files to `MyAwesomeApp_v1.2.3.4_DebugInfo.pdb` or so, after downloading it just rename to the original. I personally find VS sensitive to file names.

This could be also hint why the timestamps are not the same. Creating the file and renaming it happened at ours at different step (close to each other, but not an atomic operation). So when it created the file around the 59th second of a minute the rename might fall in the next minute and boom - 9:03 just turned 9:04.